# How to render with conditions in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Having this classic render method:

```
render() {
  ...
  return (
    <div> ... </div>
  );
}
```

my question is how can it be returned something different based on a condition?

For example, in my case it is a value on the state: `this.state.value` - if this value is true - return something, if it is false - return something else.

I've tried several ways but didn't find a working solution.

1. Ternary inside return:

```
render() {
  ...
  return (
    {this.state.value ? 
       <div> something </div>
     : <div> something else </div>
    }
  );
}
```

this one says: **Parsing error: Unexpected keyword 'this'**

2. if-else

```
render() {
  ...
  return (
    {
      if(this.state.value) { 
       <div> something </div> 
      } else {
        <div> something else </div>
      }
    }
  );
}
```

it has the same error as above.

When I've tried to make an if-else statement with `return ( ... );` for both if and else it says:  **Unnecessary 'else' after 'return'  no-else-return**

How can it return something different based on the value of `this.state.value`?

Comment: You need either `if (this.state.value) return (<div>...</div>); else return (<div>...</div>);` or `return (<>{this.state.value ? <div>...</div> : <div>...</div>}</>);` or simply `return (this.state.value ? <div>...</div> : <div>...</div>);` Wrapping expression in curly braces is only done inside JSX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need to wrap ternary conditions within `{}` The following will work

```
render() {
  ...
  return this.state.value ? 
       <div> something </div>
     : <div> something else </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
return this.state.value
 ? <div> something </div>
 : <div> something else </div>;
```

or

```
if (this.state.value) { 
  return <div> something </div>;
} else {
  return <div> something else </div>;
}
```

In the first case you had extra {} around the return value, in the second case `return if` is not possible in JS since `if` does not return anything.

Consider JSX tags to be function calls (they're actually transpiled to calls to `React.createElement`).